# Raspberry pi zero don't see i2c device

Tags: pi-zero, python-3

I try to connect to raspberry pi zero by `i2c` bus 3 different devices: 3 accelerometers `mpu6050`, 1 barometer `BMP280`, 1 compass `QMC5883L`. The `mpu6050`, `BMP280` and `QMC5883L` have a different addresses. `mpu6050` can change the address from `0x68` to `0x69` by applying high or low voltage to `AD0`, so i sequentially reading data, switching the address I need on the device at the right time. but there's a problem: if everything is connected according to the figure below, then pi sees only two sensors types `mpu6050` and `BMP280`. If disconnect all `mpu6050`, pi sees `BMP280` and `QMC5883L`. I thought that the problem might be in the power supply, so I separately powered the `QMC5883L`, but it gave nothing. to check devices, I used the command in the terminal:

```
sudo i2cdetect -y 1
```

and python gives an error when `mpu6050` is connected, and `QMC5883L` is not visible

```
OSError: [Errno 121] Remote I/O error
```

[image]

Comment: You should not need to use sudo with i2cdetect.  Can you supply a set of clear photos showing the connections made when two devices work and a set of clear photos showing the connections made when the third device is added?  Without such photos you are unlikely to get any useful help.

Comment: Do not post pictures of text post TEXT.

Comment: @אליהו I have appended the additional information you added as an answer to the bottom of your question. Please use the `Edit` button at the bottom of your question to make changes as necessary. Additional information can be added as edits to your question. As Milliways has already said any text should be posted as text in the question instead of pictures of text.

Comment: I could not add pictures at all, since the connection diagram was in the original figure

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think i found solution for my problem. I just will create a few i2c buses following this instruction
https://www.instructables.com/Raspberry-PI-Multiple-I2c-Devices/